# Strange old very off-topic question with ridiculous answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290359/artificial-intelligence-what-to-put-in-or-leave-out-and-what-can-be-inferred#comment59210451_290359) in a discussion in a chat room. Apparently this question was once in semi-high regard, considering the +17 upvotes it got and the upvoted answers in it. What seems even weirder is the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/290359/revisions), specifically the tags on it.

I know 20k'ers can't delete this atm due to the upvoted and accepted answer, but I don't think it's worth a historic significance lock, so what do we do with this?

Comment: Stack Overflow was just three months out of beta at the time that was posted. Nothing weird about the question or any of the answers.

Comment: @BoltClock What do you think should be done with it? Should it be kept? Historic significance lock? Moderator deletion? I don't know.

Comment: Made me laugh how unrelated was that question and answers to programming, and the given and ACCEPTED answer there. It is even offtopic in philosophy.SE site.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli If you edited it a bit you could _maybe_ manage to make it on-topic for Worldbuilding.se

Comment: @Ajedi32 you made my day

Comment: What I find interesting about that question is how all the people advocating in the comments for keeping that question open are relatively low-rep today, while those in opposition to the question ([Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10755/tim), [Mark Biek](http://stackoverflow.com/users/305/mark-biek), and [Patrick Desjardins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13913/patrick-desjardins)) are now high-rep users who are still relatively active on SO.

Comment: but, it happened while they were programming, so clearly it's on topic

Comment: @Kevin B: But were they programming *on a boat*?

Comment: Look at that awesome guy [Jon Seigel](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/290359/revisions) removing those crap tags. What a guy. (Spoiler: He was my room mate in 2010 and got me into Stack Overflow)

Comment: I see, back then people ( current moderators ) had fun.

Comment: I'm only reading this thread because it popped up on the right "hot meta posts" thingy.  So I go to read what it's all about, because I could use a chuckle.  And the post that you're all discussing is gone already.  sheesh...  Seriously though...  Does one question with a string of answers take up so much space in the database that garbage collection is even necessary?

Comment: Can we link a screenshot of the question and its answers for the <10k?

Comment: Several of the answers, disturbingly, look as though they were generated by AI

Comment: Nice, we've deleted a question and replaced it with a question about the deleted question. How is SO better for this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Stack Overflow was just three months out of beta at the time that was posted. Nothing weird about the question or any of the answers.

That being said, I don't see anything of lasting value there, so I deleted the question. I don't think any of the users who answered that question will mind. They probably don't even remember answering it.

Comment: WHAT?! OMG! Here goes the tyrannical moderators deleting everything again! That question had brilliant answers, like *"Without the bad, the good is meaningless."* That insight changed my life.

Comment: now the question has been deleted, there's no point in having this question around is there? BTW I'm 100% agreeing with @CodyGray that you shouldn't have deleted the original rather than suggesting you actually delete this one, but I can't see that this question adds any value now

Comment: I wanted to read those answers so bad and now I can't... :(

Comment: @EricMartinez [Here you go](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tJ5zjC11a0YJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/290359/artificial-intelligence-what-to-put-in-or-leave-out-and-what-can-be-inferred+).

Comment: @EricMartinez: Time to gather some rep ;)

Comment: Google cache still serves the curious http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tJ5zjC11a0YJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/290359/artificial-intelligence-what-to-put-in-or-leave-out-and-what-can-be-inferred+&cd=1&hl=sv&ct=clnk&gl=se

Comment: @Schaki: user11153 posted that already.

Comment: @EricMartinez [Wayback machine has it with formatting](https://web.archive.org/web/20150509032918/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290359/artificial-intelligence-what-to-put-in-or-leave-out-and-what-can-be-inferred)

Comment: Let's hope the AI we create someday isn't as eager as we are to dispose of things with no apparent lasting value.

Comment: So the real reason for the existence of skynet is that its programmer looked on stackoverflow if he was supposed to teach both good and bad in its brand new AI and found nothing because the question was deleted so he decided to go with its own ideas

Comment: @EricMartinez Good luck [getting to 10k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/how-do-you-view-deleted-questions) before it's been too long to retrieve it. Or you could [go here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tJ5zjC11a0YJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/290359/artificial-intelligence-what-to-put-in-or-leave-out-and-what-can-be-inferred+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). ;^) *" 
This is nonsense and ethics drivel. Time for me to get back to real work. Amazing how the OP chose this as the "answer"."* Ha!

Answer (score 38):

I think we better spend our time and very limited number of votes on new stuff coming in.

That question was last active in 2011 and only gathered 897 views. It doesn't do much harm, it could have survived for another couple of years easily.

My take on old questions is: Only moderate when they become active or are used as an example of questions that can be asked on the site. That is the signal that the question is starting to hurt a bit.

You could bring it up on meta and with some luck you'll find a moderator that uses one of their delete votes to destroy the question. Which happened as I'm typing this answer. Peace is restored.

Comment: "Peace is restored". The way I'm feeling right now, I'm to think quite the opposite would happen.

Comment: Site moderation is one of our overall ongoing tasks though, so I don't agree that we should do *nothing* if there's been no activity on the question. Personally I follow *"Moderate when you see a problem, but don't go looking for one"*, which was raised on a meta somewhere that I can't remember. It means if you find stuff like this question, do something, but we shouldn't be actively sifting through all old questions looking for other ridiculous/weird questions to moderate.